# Salesforce Crm content general questions

Tags: knowledge, content

We are planning on getting the Salesforce Lightning Enterprise edition. We need to use the Salesforce `Crm Content`. When I checked on the licenses it said the Lightning Enterprise edition comes with `Content Library`.

I have the following questions. (I'm new to this).

1. Are Salesforce `Crm Content` and `Content Library` one and the same?
2. If the answer to the above question is yes, do we need not get additional license to the `Crm Content`?
3. I have read about "Knowledge". So if we plan on using this Salesforce `Crm content`, does it mean that it has all the features of `Knowledge` and so we need not use `Knowledge` again along with `Crm Content`. Or do we have to use both?

[image: This is a snapshot of the licenses]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Are Salesforce Crm Content and Content Library one and the same?**
From [this](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gqOZAAY) answer

> Libraries allow you to create and categorize content (files) in
>   logical groups.  We can have one ore more libraries and provide
>   security around it (as in you could have a library specific to a
>   group/business unit and make sure nobody else except the intended
>   users will be able to access the content (files) within that library).
>   See this page for more details:
>   http://www.salesforce.com/crm/sales-force-automation/content-management/

**If the answer to the above question is yes, do we need not get additional license to the Crm Content?**
CRM Content is a feature license, which you can read about [here](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/08/25/salesforce-com-licenses/). It seems that it would be included in the version your company is considering, though.

**I have read about "Knowledge". So if we plan on using this Salesforce Crm content, does it mean that it has all the features of Knowledge and so we need not use Knowledge again along with Crm Content. Or do we have to use both?**

Here's a short [document](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h2CWAAY) explaining the difference between the two. You can use both, or neither or one as long as you have the necessary licenses.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, from the screenshot you provided it looks like you are looking for Salesforce for Non-profit organization (free first 10 licenses and discounted after).

In regard of your questions 1&2, I believe CRM Content and Content Libraries are the same and do not require additional license, however, depending on [edition you will use](https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing), you might not have access to some (if not all) CRM functionality (Leads updates, opportunities, orders..) and any delivered integrations with Content Libraries.

Knowledge, as [brezotom stated in his answer](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h2CWAAY), is a different thing - it's collection of searchable articles and can be used as a wiki for the internal and external users.